# Using Axios and Vue to fetch api data - returning undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

Running into a snag with trying to integrate my API with Vue/Axios. Basically, Axios is getting the data (it DOES console.log what I want)... But when I try to get that data to my empty variable (in the data object of my component) to store it, it throws an "undefined at eval" error. Any ideas on why this isn't working for me? Thanks!

```
<template>
  <div class="wallet-container">
    <h1 class="title">{{ title }}</h1>
    <div class="row">
      {{ thoughtWallet }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';
export default {

  name: 'ThoughtWallet',
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'My ThoughtWallet',
      thoughtWallet: [],
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.loadThoughtWallet();
  },
  methods: {
    loadThoughtWallet: function() {
      this.thoughtWallet[0] = 'Loading...',
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/thoughts').then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data); // DISPLAYS THE DATA I WANT
        this.thoughtWallet = response.data; // THROWS TYPE ERROR: Cannot set property 'thoughtWallet' of undefined at eval
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: I think the problem is you are trying to print the object..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you're using `.then(function(..) { })` `this` won't refer to the vue context `this`.

You have two solutions, one is to set a variable that references the `this` you want before the axios call, e.g.:

```
var that = this.thoughtWallet
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/thoughts').then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data); // DISPLAYS THE DATA I WANT
        that = response.data; // THROWS TYPE ERROR: Cannot set property 'thoughtWallet' of undefined at eval
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

The other is to use the new syntax (for which you need to make sure your code is transpiled correctly for browsers that don't support it yet), which allows you to access `this` inside the scoped body of the axios then.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/thoughts').then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data); // DISPLAYS THE DATA I WANT
        this.thoughtWallet = response.data; // THROWS TYPE ERROR: Cannot set property 'thoughtWallet' of undefined at eval
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

The reason this happens is because inside that function/then, `this` will be referring to the context of the function, hence there won't be a `thoughtWallet` property

Comment: Very helpful explanation. Thank you!

Comment: `The reason this happens is because inside that function/then, this will be referring to the context of the function, hence there won't be a thoughtWallet property.` - >Unfortunately, there's literally hundreds of Vue + axios tutorial that teaches us to pass the result from axios by doing `this.variable` inside get or post method

Answer (score 4):

`this.thoughtWallet` inside the `.get` method is referring to the axios object, not Vue's. You can simply define Vue's `this` on the start:

```
methods: {
  loadThoughtWallet: function() {
    let self = this;

    this.thoughtWallet[0] = 'Loading...',
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/thoughts').then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data); // DISPLAYS THE DATA I WANT

      self.thoughtWallet = response.data;

    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.thoughtWallet inside the .get method is referring to the axios object, not Vue's.` - >Unfortunately, there's literally hundreds of Vue + axios tutorial that teaches us to pass the result from axios by doing `this.variable` inside get or post method