# axios GET request doesn't return any data (VueJS & NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, json, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to make an API call from front-end (vueJS) to back-end (nodeJS). This is my code handling the original api request in the back-end:

```
app.route('/myplaylists')
   .get(function(req, res) {
      spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists({ limit: 1, offset: 1 })
      .then(function(data) {
        res.send('Success! Playlists fetched.');
        const tbr = JSON.stringify(data.body.items[0], null, 4);
        console.log('Retrieved playlists', tbr);
        });
      },function(err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
      });
});
```

I'm using [this](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) wrapper as you can see, but I don't think it matters. This part of the code works fine, as I do get the desired outcome printed in the terminal, which is:

```
{
    "collaborative": false,
    "description": "The songs you loved most this year, all wrapped up.",
    "external_urls": {
        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1ELWjgC8Aiv78C"
    },
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1ELWjgC8Aiv78C",
    "id": "37i9dQZF1ELWjgC8Aiv78C",
    "images": [
        {
            "height": null,
            "url": "https://lineup-images.scdn.co/wrapped-2020-top100_LARGE-en.jpg",
            "width": null
        }
    ],
    "name": "Your Top Songs 2020",
    "owner": {
        "display_name": "Spotify",
        "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/user/spotify"
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify",
        "id": "spotify",
        "type": "user",
        "uri": "spotify:user:spotify"
    },
    "primary_color": null,
    "public": false,
    "snapshot_id": "MjY3NzQ1NzIsMDAwMDAwMDA1NTUxYmQyZGVhMzAwODYxYzQ5ZmMwMDRhMmUyMDRkOQ==",
    "tracks": {
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1ELWjgC8Aiv78C/tracks",
        "total": 100
    },
    "type": "playlist",
    "uri": "spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1ELWjgC8Aiv78C"
}
```

And this is my vue component making the api req:

```
<template>
<div id="thisisatest">
    <h1>This is a page to test api calls.</h1>
    <h2>
        The json result should be displayed here:
    </h2>
    <p>{{ info }}</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'About',
    data () {
        return {
            info: null
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        axios
            this.$http
            .get('http://localhost:8888/myplaylists')
            .then(response => (this.info = response.body.items[0]))
            // .catch(error => alert(error))
    },
};
</script>
```

but the `{{ info }}` part is not displayed. Some things to note:

1. The request reaches the back-end correctly, because like I mentioned, the expected outcome is printed in the terminal.
2. If I uncomment the `// .catch(error => alert(error))` part, I do get an alert saying `"Error: Network Error"`
3. I thought the problem was on the `.then(response => (this.info = response.body.items[0]))` part, as I've already "edited" the JSON part in the back-end, but neither did `.then(response =>(this.info = response))` work, nor `.then(response =>(this.info = response.body))`.
4. Basically, the assignment to `info` is not happening, because if I change the `.catch` to `.catch(alert(this.info))` I get `null` in the alert.
5. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468509/using-axios-and-vue-to-fetch-api-data-returning-undefined), too. `mounted` would look like that:

```
mounted () {
   var temp = this.info;
   axios
   this.$http
       .get('http://localhost:8888/myplaylists')
       .then(response => (temp = response.body.items[0]))
```

but then I get an `35:13  error  'temp' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars` error.

EDIT: In response to Matt's comment, firstly `response.data.items` also doesn't work. Then, after changing the `.catch` to `.catch(error => console.error(error))` I get the following in Inspect Element:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb7Kz.png) and [this Network output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egO5v.png)

Comment: For axios it will be `response.data.items` but a `Network Error` is before that. Log the error with `console.error` and check the network tab for the failed response and add that info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, as I ended up changing a lot of things.
As you can see in the console output photo I included, I got an error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked (...)

[This was a cors error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin) due to the servers running in different localhosts (8080 for frontend and 8888 for backend). I solved this by including the following in my `app.js` file, as I am using `express` as well:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Also, it should be `response.data` at that `mounted` part in the front-end request.